# Regex for match all math operations

Tags: python, regex

I have this data:

```
data = """
r = !(7225 + -2932 + 1 * -4293), (i, dc, r), i[qo] = void(1 * 7333 + 9158 + -16491);
c = (t, -20 * -28 + -8172 + 8750),
i = 1706 + 6792 + 14 * -607;
{}, [8709 * -1 + 46925 + 1 * 3786]
"""
```

How to match all that math operations?
I'd like to match them, and replace to get result e.g:

```
data = """
r = !(0), (i, dc, r), i[qo] = void(0);
c = (t, 1138),
i = 0;
{}, [42002]
"""
```

Any idea?

Comment: Somehow you have to find all substrings with math expressions. Then it is simply `eval(substring)` to convert math expression to value. Probably all substrings can be found using regex. I'll try to code this solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLboMwELz7K7a5xAaSYiAYiKp8CPYhCo5qKQFqXKQqyrfTtZuqj73YMzs7s5bHD/c69PmydPoMp6GfaXd0R9YQwDLXcbAOrA7oPFi4gukRz9pOuqMXMzlq9fZs@s44bWnQfZdd00PTykg@y1hu5KQi2cVIya3sInZgN57c1wmEPPZI9OUJeIGwSNtct9N47GnK2lQpiP8kTM5SPR8vX9LfSmjgB3KlGIMY/qm4ahQLfla7d9uHPiGP@NVqRSyeT1Rk2Q6nN1mdZ3hyiGBTIGAJUIP7nxKweDft26BwYB5MR71I5HmO@prvKj/Oy6LmbE9O/m0uQb/UO2WhWXHhvSuxS1lCDEq4SEtkSlGH0MJry1Tsye2eQFuJtPYMx15R1mFBn5mLqlTE705Ga3pHf76ULcsn)

```
def conv(data):
    import re
    for m in reversed(list(re.finditer(
            r'(?:[\*\/\+\-\s]*\d+(?:\.\d*)?){1,}', data))):
        data = (data[:m.span(0)[0]] +
            str(eval(data[m.span(0)[0] : m.span(0)[1]])) + data[m.span(0)[1]:])
    return data

data = """
r = !(7225 + -2932 + 1 * -4293), (i, dc, r), i[qo] = void(1 * 7333 + 9158 + -16491);
c = (t, -20 * -28 + -8172 + 8750),
i = 1706 + 6792 + 14 * -607;
{}, [8709 * -1 + 46925 + 1 * 3786]
"""

print(conv(data))
```

Output:

```
r = !(0), (i, dc, r), i[qo] = void(0);
c = (t,1138),
i =0;
{}, [42002]
```